# Do embeded Vimeo videos on website count towards the site's CDN usage?

Tags: embed, cdn, vimeo, cloudways

I have read varying responses to this but I am needing to know if my site plays and embedded Vimeo video will it count towards CDN billing? What do you think? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does not. When embedding a Vimeo asset on your site, it's likely using an iframe. e.g.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/XXXXXXXX" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p><a href="https://vimeo.com/XXXXXXXX">Video Title</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/user">User</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Let's say a user requests the HTML page from your domain. Your CDN sends the HTML page (with the iframe code) to the user. This counts against your billing. Once the page is loaded by the user's browser, the browser reads the iframe and pulls the video content from vimeo.com (notice the iframe src value). Your CDN does not deliver video bits for Vimeo so you are not billed for that traffic.